# How to have auto-reloading i18n while using Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Please tell me how can I use i18n in Nuxt.js with lang files? I want to edit my lang file on the server after build, but there is no change. Do I have to re-do npm run build every time? Nightmare!

I'm using i18n.nuxtjs.org

I want @/lang/en.json to watch and automatically change after repeated yarn start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yarn dev` during development. It will reload you app to take the i18n changes into account.

`yarn build` or `yarn generate` are used for production builds.